# What is the difference between these two generic functions?

Tags: java, generics

As the title says, I am wondering what the difference between those functions is.
Why should/shouldn't I provide the `<T>` in foo2

```
public class Base<T> {

    public T[] foo(int i){
        /*Do something*/

    }

    public <T> T[] foo2(int i){
        /*Do something*/
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `T` of your second function hides the type parameter `T` of your class. This means that `T` in the second function referes to a *different* type `T`. This naming is confusing and should be avoided.

You can, of course, do this if you actually want to refer to a different generic type, but you should name the type parameter differently. The following example is equivalent to yours but does not hide `T` defined in `Base`:

```
public class Base<T> {

    public T[] foo(int i){
        /*Do something*/

    }

    public <S> S[] foo2(int i){
        /*Do something*/
    }
}
```